# Trying to Read a Line of Keyboard Input in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, cin

I mam trying to complete a college assignment in C++ and am having trouble with what should be a very basic operation. I am trying to read a string of characters from the keyboard. This is the relevant code:

```
  string t;
  cout << endl << "Enter title to search for: ";
  getline(cin, t, '\n');
```

I understand, that the last line is supposed to read the input buffer (cin , in this instance) and store the character in the 't' string until it reaches a new line character and then continue the program flow.

However, when I run my code in XCode, it just sort of jumps over the `getline` function and treats 't' as an empty string.

What's going on?  I tried using `cin >> t` but that just read characters forever - Why cant I get this to behave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that the input operation apparently is skipped, is most probably (that means, ignoring possible peculiarities of a bugsy XCode IDE) that you have performed some input earlier and *left a newline in the input buffer*.

To fix that, make sure that you have emptied the input buffer after each input operation that logically should consume a line of input.

One easy way is to always use `getline` into a `string`, and then use e.g. an `istringstream` if you want to convert a number specification to number type.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Exactly correct in all respects (and istringstream rocks btw!), thank-you very much.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) it looks like you want

```
cin.getline(t,256,'\n');
```

or something similar.

Comment: There are actually multiple versions of getline. There is the standalone function std::getline() and also std::istream::getline(). http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with the way Xcode is running your program. Try running your program directly from the terminal, and see if this is sufficient to fix your issue.